# Sending a Static Value as a Parameter in an Event Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

Using Javascript (and jQuery), I have an array of several objects.  For each object in that array, I'm adding a small, clickable image to a div.  Clicking each small image will change the path of a large image, thus showing a new picture.

Here's what I've got:

```
for (s = 0; s < splash.length; s += 1)
  {
  // add a new dot to this row
  $(".splash_dots").append ("<div class = 'dot' id = 'dot" + s + "'><img src = 'images/dot2.png'></div>");

  var id = 'dot' + s;

  // add a click handler
  document.getElementById (id).addEventListener ("click", function () {change_splash (s)});
  }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

function change_splash (s)
  {
  // load a new image for the large photo
  $(".splash").attr ("src", splash[s].screenshot_link);
  }
```

This almost works.  The problem is that when change_splash() is called, I'm expecting the value of s to be what it was when the loop added the handler.  For example, clicking the first dot will call change_splash(0).  However, it's actually sending what s is when the click happens (after the loops ends, which is always array.length).

I have a temporary solution, but I don't like it::

```
if (s === 0) document.getElementById (id).addEventListener ("click", function () {change_splash (0)});
if (s === 1) document.getElementById (id).addEventListener ("click", function () {change_splash (1)});
```

This just seems really inefficient.

I'm basically just trying to create a sliding splash advertisement, like what you'd see on almost any retail homepage, so I know it's possible.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need a closure:

```
(function(id,s){
 document.getElementById(id)
  .addEventListener("click", function(){change_splash (s)});}(id,s));
```

Comment: or you could by like @Tom and use the loop body as a closure

Comment: @ Markasoftware: His suggestion doesn't create a closure nor will it have the desired result.

Comment: This works great.  I moved "var id" inside the closure to eliminate that parameter and simplify things slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
for (var s in splash){
    // create the points, stores the id in the data-id attribute
    $(".splash_dots").append ("<div class ='dot' data-id='" + s + "'><img src='images/dot2.png'></div>");
}

// click listener
$("body").on("click",".dot",function(){
    // retrieve the id from the data-id attribute
    var s = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $(".splash").attr ("src", splash[s].screenshot_link);
});
```

See it in action in [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/51zr5pn5/)

Comment: Thanks, in this way you don't have to worry about sending parameters to closures, or about the variables' scopes.